# How to select all words and quotation marks without white space foreword?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

If there are something like this in vim:
`text = 'hellowo|rld'`

The `|` is the cursor,and when I input `va'`, it will be `text =[ 'helloworld']|`, notice that white space foreword is also included.

Is there any way to exclude the white space foreword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, there's actually a better way. I checked the help page (`:h i'`), and this will actually work:

```
v2i'
```

(I didn't know that before!) From the help page:

```
        Special case: With a count of 2 the quotes are
        included, but no extra white space as with a"/a'/a`.
```

You can map this in your vimrc to make visual mode always behave this way (and even other operators, like `y` or `d`):

```
vnoremap a' 2i'
vnoremap a" 2i"
vnoremap a` 2i`
onoremap a' 2i'
onoremap a" 2i"
onoremap a` 2i`
```

---

Old answer:

It's a bit inelegant, but you can use `va'ol` (visual around quotes, go to the other side of the visual selection, and move one char to the left).

If you want visual mode to *always* behave way, here's a quick hack that gets it done (put it in your vimrc):

```
vnoremap a' i'loho
```

(That's just "inside quotes, extend one left, switch to the other side, extend one right, switch back.")